# Rspec Unit Testing for self.from_omniauth(auth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |partner|
      partner.provider = auth.provider
      partner.uid = auth.uid
      partner.email = auth.info.email      || ''
      partner.lastname = auth.info.last_name  || ''
      partner.firstname = (auth.provider == "twitter") ? auth["info"]["name"] : auth.info.first_name
      partner.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token || ''
      partner.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at) if auth.provider == "facebook"
      partner.auth_token = partner.auth_token.present? ? partner.auth_token : ''
      partner.company_api_access = partner.company_api_access.present? ? partner.company_api_access : "In Progress"
      partner.save(:validate => false)
    end
  end
```

This is my from_omniauth method that I want to add Rspect Unit testing So How Can I do this?

I search many things but that includes controller also that I don't want.

I just want to test a method so How can I ?

Please Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means the cleanest solution, but since this question has been up for a year without an answer I'll post it. This is essentially what you should try to do. This example is for facebook, but it should work similarly for other providers.

```
auth_hash = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  :provider => 'facebook',
  :uid => '1234',
  :info => {
    :email => "user@example.com",
    :name => "Justin Bieber"
  }
})

describe User, "#from_omniauth" do
    it "retrieves an existing user" do
        user = User.new(
            :provider => "facebook", 
            :uid => 1234,
            :email => "user@example.com",
            :password => 'password', 
            :password_confirmation => 'password'
            )
        user.save
        omniauth_user = User.from_omniauth(auth_hash)

        expect(user).to eq(omniauth_user)
  end

  it "creates a new user if one doesn't already exist" do
    expect(User.count).to eq(0)

    omniauth_user = User.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
    expect(User.count).to eq(1)
  end
end
```